# Using the same bot on different servers

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to use my reminder bot on two servers at the same time, but the problem is whenever someone uses a command on one of the servers it will interact with the current loop.

To make things easier: my bot sends a msg for every X seconds to remind the user of the command to doing something. However when someone else uses it, it will overwrite the current loop function and result in not being able to stop but only the last loop.

im using `@tasks.loop(seconds=time)` and `task.start()` and `task.cancel()` in order to control the loop.

so i was wondering if there is a way to give a unique id to the loop so when i want to cancel it, it will search for that specific loop and cancel it (in case there are many reminders currently running).

Answer (score 0):

If your task is setup as a class - then you could theoretically just create a new instance of that class everytime you want to start a new reminder.

---

Though, I would personally find a way to save state about data about the reminders elsewhere and use a single task. Either just using a dictionary, a file on the disk, or a DB of some kind.

The data saved for each reminder would need to be something like:

- guild ID: the server ID the reminder is for
- channel ID: the channel ID we need to send the message to
- user ID: the user that triggered the reminder
- active: whether the reminder is active or not
- reminder(?): what we're reminding the user to do (if this is configurable)

That way:

- your task can just loop every X minutes (however often you want the reminders to be triggered) and it will check if there's any active reminders (in your dict, file, db, etc). If there isn't it can just return until the next iteration
- users in either server can start reminders. however you're starting them would need to add a 'reminder object' either to the dict, file, db, etc
- if there is active reminders, the task can loop over them and send the reminder to the relevant guild/channel/user as per the data
- in your `on_message` method, you can turn the reminder(s) on/off as required

Hopefully that makes a bit of sense.